# subsets of discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I think all are possible since B could use Riemann function as an example and C&D could use a function which equals -3x when x is rational and 5x when x is irrational. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Take a continuous function every where.

B. Take $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{q_n \leq x}\frac{1}{n^2}$ where $\{q_1,...,q_n..\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals.

C. It is not possible,because it is a known fact that the set of continuity points of a functions is $G_{\delta}$ i.e a countable intersection of open sets.So the set of discontinuities must be $F_{\sigma}$ i.e a countable union of closed sets.

But the set of irrational numbers is not $F_{\sigma}$ since the set of rationals is not $G_{\delta}$ by Baire's Category theorem.

D. Take $f:(0,+\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin \Bbb{Q}$

E. Take the Dirichlet function.

> So only $C$ is impossible.

Comment: Hi! If I take Dirichret's function. Then it is discontinuous everywhere. And surely it is discontinuous on the irrationals. Is this correct?

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question then..Do you want a function which has all discontinuities ONLY the irrationals, or a functions that has the irrationals as a proper subset of the set of discontinuities??..i think it is the first case if you ask me. because it would be too easy..you would take for the  first case a continuous funtion and for the other cases the Dirichlet function.